# multiple data types for a mongo variable

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine

I am using php, mongodb and dctrine. Is there a way to set multiple data types for a mongo variable.

my variable needed to be changed with multiple data types as follows.

```
/** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
private $value;
```

Comment: I thin, the better option is creating a custom data type. Hope this will help me. 

Here is the doctrine documentation.
http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#custom-mapping-types